# Convert MULTIPOLYGON string to a MULTIPOLYGON object for graphing in R

Tags: r, plot, geom, multipolygons

I have a data frame with a character column where each observation looks like this:

[1] "MULTIPOLYGON (((-108.80001058777736 37.10000583381149, -108.70001056633824 37.10000584006442, -108.70001055671808 37.00084259698653, -108.80001057814715 37.00084259698653, -108.80001058777736 37.10000583381149)))"

I have scored the internet and cannot find a solution. I need to convert this to a geometric MULTIPOLYGON object that is ready for graphing, which looks like this:

Geometry set for 1 feature
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -105.1783 ymin: 39.91388 xmax: -105.0528 ymax: 40.07297
Geodetic CRS:  NAD83
MULTIPOLYGON (((-105.0823 39.95936, -105.0817 3...

Anyone have any idea?

I tried `st_multipolygon` but it requires a list of lists but it produced an error.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.